# (Powershell) Textbox to search text

Tags: powershell, search

I have a textbox that lists all the software on a machine, but I want to have a search bar below it that lets me search for things from that list.

Preferably I would like to do this where as I type it starts to parse out the items in the original textbox. But if it has to have a search button, that is fine too.

This may not be doable in powershell either, not 100% sure.
Any suggestions are appreciated, normally I would give a line of code that I have tried but I am actually at a loss here and not sure where to start as the few things I have tried have not remotely done what I want.

--Edit

```
$SysInfo = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Textbox
$SysInfo.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(5,5)
$SysInfo.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(520,290)
$SysInfo.AutoSize = $true
$SysInfo.Multiline = $true
$SysInfo.ScrollBars = "Vertical"
$SysInfo.AcceptsReturn = $true
$SysInfo.AcceptsTab = $false
$SysInfo.WordWrap = $true
$SysInfo.Enabled = $True

$SysInfo.text = Get-WmiObject -Computer ($ComputerName) -Class Win32_Product | Select-Object -Property Name, Version |
            Select-Object -Property * | Sort-Object Name |
            Out-String
```

--EDIT
Using the reddit post mentioned below. I cant get any of these to work.

```
$Services = Get-Service | Select-object $Fields

$Services = Get-Service -ComputerName $ComputerName | Select-object $Fields

$Services = Get-WmiObject -Computer $ComputerName -Class Win32_Product | Select-Object -Property $Fields |
            Select-Object -Property * | Sort-Object $Fields |
            Out-String
```

Running

```
$Services = Get-Service -Computername $ComputerName| Select-object $Fields
```

Only pulls my machine, its not letting me pull info from other machines. Its not throwing any errors or giving me any debug logs

---Solved

```
Function Software-Pull {

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')
[xml]$XAML = @'
<Window Name="Form"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="Common Software" Height="488.773" Width="797.65" Icon = "\\bconac01\ds-support\GS_IT\Tools\Test Tools (Alx)\Tool\icon.ico" ShowInTaskbar="False"> 
    <Grid Margin="0,0,-8,-21">
        <DataGrid Name="DataGrid1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="368" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="772" Margin="10,41,0,0"/>
        <Label Content="Filter" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox Name="FilterTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="78,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="172"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
'@

#Read XAML
$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml) 
try{$Form2=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )}
catch{Write-Host "Unable to load Windows.Markup.XamlReader. Some possible causes for this problem include: .NET Framework is missing PowerShell must be launched with PowerShell -sta, invalid XAML code was encountered."; exit}

# Store Form Objects In PowerShell
$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | ForEach-Object{
    Set-Variable -Name ($_.Name) -Value $Form2.FindName($_.Name)
    Write-host $_.Name
}

$Fields = @(
    'Name'
    'Version'
)



$Services = Get-WmiObject -Computer ($prebox.text + $device.text) -Class Win32_Product | Select-object -Property *



# Add Services to a datatable
$Datatable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
[void]$Datatable.Columns.AddRange($Fields)
foreach ($Service in $Services)
{
    $Array = @()
    Foreach ($Field in $Fields)
    {
        $array += $Service.$Field
    }
    [void]$Datatable.Rows.Add($array)
}
#$filter = "DisplayName LIKE 'B%'"
#$Datatable.DefaultView.RowFilter = $filter

# Create a datagrid object and populate with datatable
$DataGrid1.ItemsSource = $Datatable.DefaultView
$DataGrid1.CanUserAddRows = $False
$DataGrid1.IsReadOnly = $True
$DataGrid1.GridLinesVisibility = "None"

$FilterTextBox.Add_TextChanged({
    $InputText = $FilterTextBox.Text
    $filter = "Name LIKE '$InputText%'"
    $Datatable.DefaultView.RowFilter = $filter
    $DataGrid1.ItemsSource = $Datatable.DefaultView
})

# Shows the form
$statusBar1.Text = "Done."
$Form2.Add_Shown({$Form2.Activate()})
$Form2.ShowDialog() | out-null

}
```

Got it to open my second forum pulling data, AddRemoveProgram doesnt seem to work with it, so this causes it to freeze for a few seconds to pull data but it all works.

Comment: Since it's literally just a block of text that you are searching, there won't be much you can do which would be useful. Why not have a `DataGrid` for each program? Please update your question with the code you are currently using, we require a minimal reproducible issue :-)

Comment: Updated. This is how I am pulling the current data.

Comment: I found this on reddit [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/adtyef/wpf_gui_with_filterable_datagrid/)

Comment: I think this is exactly what I am looking for, youre a saint <3

Comment: The only issue I am having with this code is its not letting me run the command on remote machines, updated OP.

Comment: Please update your question with the specific issues/errors you are getting from the `Get-Service` commands :) Also, once everything has been figured out, please post your answer as to how you solved the issue

Comment: Noted. I added to the OP.
I cant get it to pull anything off the network, and I am having issues getting it to pull software instead of services, but I think I can handle that just need to dig through some of the lines a bit more.